# getPurchase() OK but getSkuDetails() NULL

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app

I can't get the sku title from my in-app project.

I follow the TrivialDrive example,

I query the inventory with

```
try {
   mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
} catch (IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
   complain("Error querying inventory. Another async operation in progress.");
}
```

I get the correct information of purchase

```
String sku = inventory.getPurchase(SKU[i]).getSku();
Long date_l = inventory.getPurchase(SKU[i]).getPurchaseTime();
```

but if a ask details I receive always null

```
inventory.hasDetails(SKU[i]);
```

The apk is in beta test.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling mHelper.queryInventoryAsync() with all four parameters.

```
List<String> skus = new ArrayList<String>();
skus.add(SKU_PREMIUM);
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true,skus, skus, mGotInventoryListener);
```

From IabHelper class

```
public void queryInventoryAsync(final boolean querySkuDetails, final List<String> moreItemSkus,
                                final List<String> moreSubsSkus, final QueryInventoryFinishedListener listener)
```

I had the same problem, both .getPurchase() and the actual purchase flow were working.
Also used the code from the TrivialDrive example so I had no idea queryInventoryAsync() could take four params. I also have no idea why this works. I suspect the "standard" flow of queryInventoryAsync(listener) only concerns itself with the purpose of checking if a used owns an item or not and needs to be specifically told to look for the other stuff.
Notice that when you call it with only the listener as your parameter your sku is nowhere to be found, so it probably wouldn't even know what to look for.